# How to get input value to controller?

Tags: laravel

How do I get the value from an input box to controller?
I tried this code, but I need the input value, please help.

```
{{ route('payslip_generate',['payslip'=>'pdf','input' => 'input value here']) }}
```

Comment: you mean a route parameter??

Answer (score 0):

From the request body you can get this by 
    $request->payslip

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The route is calculated before the page is rendered. If you want to submit a value in an input box, you have to use a submit button on the form or some form of javascript. (e.g. axios, jquery, etc)

Here's a jQuery option:

```
        $("#element").click(function () {
        var data = {
            payslip: "pdf",
            input: $("#other-input").val()
        };

        $.post("/payslip_generate", data, function (response) {
            console.log("success");
        }).fail(function (response) {
            console.log("ERROR ", response);
        });
    });
```

Comment: is it possible to use jquery and pass it to the laravel controller?